# Installing and running GDB on VSCODE with WSL

Tags: debugging

Everytime I install this POS software and attempt to debug it either tells me my path is wrong or "a.out doesn't exist". I'll paste my launch.json.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program":  "${fileDirname}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },  
    
]
```

}

As far as I know this should work, but right now I am being told my miDebuggerPath is invalid. Please help, this laptop is gonna get thrown onto a highway if I can't debug my program.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't reinitializing my WSL environment. Also deleting the whole .vscode folder within my directory and then recreating it solved it.